# Connecting XMLRPCSERVER using socket module

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, xmlrpclib, simplexmlrpcserver

Consider `XMLRPCSERVER` is running and we want to connect that server and call one method.

I know, we can do using `xmlrpclib` (`ServerProxy`).

But the problem is I want to connect to `XMLRPCSERVER` using `https` protocol not `http`.

I have two questions :

1. When trying to connect to server using ServerProxy, I am getting `HTTPBad Status` issue. I already tried using `ssl context` and `Safe Transport`. But still facing issue. How to solve this issue?
2. How to connect `XMLRPCSERVER` using `socket` module and call method there?

**NOTE:** Due to confidentiality reason, can't share a code of `XMLRPCSERVER`.

Comment: Which version of Python (there is a change with Python >= 3,5)

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE - I am using 2.7.13